# \K operator does not work in std::regex_replace regex

Tags: c++, regex

The value of `name` is: `regex101: build, test, and debug regex - 3 running windows`
im trying to remove everything forward the last   `-`

```cpp
std::wstring name = accvector[i].name;
std::wregex regexp(L".*\\K( -\\s+\\d+\\srunning.*$)");
name = std::regex_replace(name, regexp, L"");
```

nothing is being replace, whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in mind that [`\K` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) is not supported by ECMAScript regex flavor (used by default in `std::wregex`/`std::regex`). It is mainly supported by PCRE, Boost, Onigmo, Python PyPi regex library.

Here, you may use

```
(.*) -\s+\d+\srunning.*
```

The replacement pattern should be `$1`.

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/PDfGhJ):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::wstring name = L"regex101: build, test, and debug regex - 3 running windows";
    std::wregex regexp(LR"((.*) -\s+\d+\srunning.*)");
    name = std::regex_replace(name, regexp, L"$1");
    std::wcout << name;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Note you do not need the `$` at the end of the pattern, `.*` matches till the end of the line/string.